# Fatal Error in Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: android-studio

The problem I am facing is after successful Compilation of my any application.I get a message saying 'IDE Fatal error. click to show it'. After I click on it, I get a box with a title ' Exception in Android studio core' with following code in it. I do get my required output but this constant message of NullpointerException is pretty annoying. I would be grateful,if somebody would help me to solve this quest.

null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.execution.ui.layout.impl.RunnerContentUi.closeAll(RunnerContentUi.java:526)
    at com.intellij.ui.docking.impl.DockManagerImpl$DockWindow$3.windowClosing(DockManagerImpl.java:583)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(AWTEventMulticaster.java:349)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2051)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(JDialog.java:681)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2009)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest packages from SDK Manager. If this doesn't work, try reinstalling Android Studio. Better yet, [download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and install the latest Android Studio (1.3.1 as of the time of writing)

Comment: Thankyou for your help mate.. I finally updated it to 1.41 beta and my problem is been eradicated..:)

Comment: From here (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) , you need to click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.